# find the index of element the number of occurence in string

Tags: python

A `Char_Record` is a 3 item list `[char, total, pos_list]` where

- `char` is a one character string
- `total` is a Nat representing the number of occurrences of `char`
- `pos_list` is a list of Nat representing the indices of `char`

Using the function `build_char_records()` should produce a sorted list with every character represented (lowercase).

For example:

```
>>>build_char_records('Hi there bye')
['',2,[2,8]]
['b',1,[9]]
['e',3,[5,7,11]]
['h',2[0,4]]
['i',1,[1]]
['r',1,[6]]
['t',1,[3]]
['y',1,[10]]
```

I just wrote it like this , I don't know how to do it, someone help please. Thanks.

```
def build_char_records(s):
    s=sorted(s)
    a=[]
    for i in range(len(s)):
```

Comment: You could probably do a regex for number of matches for each character. i.e. "a": `count = len(re.match(/[a]/g, phrase).groups())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the other answers given thus far are better answers from an overall programming perspective, but based on your question I think this answer is appropriate for your skill level

```
def build_char_records(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.lower()
    resultList = []
    for character in phrase: ## iterates through the phrase
        if character not in resultList:
            resultList.append(character) ## This adds each character to the list
                                         ## if it is not already in the list        
    resultList.sort() ## sorts the list
    for i in range(len(resultList)): ## goes through each unique character
        character = resultList[i] ## the character in question
        tphrase = phrase ## a copy of the phrase
        num = phrase.count(character) ## the number of occurences
        acc = 0 ## an accumulator to keep track of how many we've found
        locs = [] ## list of the locations

        while acc < num: ## while the number we've found is less than how many
                         ## there should be
            index = tphrase.find(character) ## finds the first occurance of the character
            tphrase = tphrase[index+1:] ## chops off everything up to and including the
                                        ## character
            if len(locs) != 0: ## if there is more than one character
                index = locs[acc-1] + index + 1 ## adjusts because we're cutting up the string
            locs.append(index)## adds the index to the list
            acc += 1 ## increases the accumulator

        resultList[i] = [character, num, locs] ## creates the result in the proper spot

    return resultList ## returns the list of lists

print build_char_records('Hi there bye')
```

This will print out `[[' ', 2, [2, 8]], ['b', 1, [9]], ['e', 3, [5, 7, 11]], ['h', 2, [0, 4]], ['i', 1, [1]], ['r', 1, [6]], ['t', 1, [3]], ['y', 1, [10]]]`

Here is a slightly shorter, cleaner version

```
def build_char_records(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.lower()
    resultList = []
    for character in phrase: 
        if character not in resultList:
            resultList.append(character) 

    resultList.sort() 
    for i in range(len(resultList)): 
        tphrase = phrase 
        num = phrase.count(resultList[i]) 
        locs = [] 

        for j in range(num):
            index = tphrase.find(resultList[i]) 
            tphrase = tphrase[index+1:]
            if len(locs) != 0:
                index = locs[acc-1] + index + 1
            locs.append(index)

        resultList[i] = [resultList[i], num, locs] 

    return resultList

print build_char_records('Hi there bye')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def build_char_records(s):
    cnt = defaultdict(int)
    positions = defaultdict(list)
    for i,c in  enumerate(s):
        cnt[c] += 1
        positions[c].append(i)
    return [  [c, cnt[c], positions[c]] for c in cnt.keys()  ]
```

Comment: well, i don't think i have learned the collections and defaultdict.Any other ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using only `list`, this is what you can do:

```
def build_char_records(s):
    records = []  # Create a list to act as a dictionary
    for idx, char in enumerate(s):
        char = char.lower()
        current_record = None  # Try to find the record in our list of records
        for record in records:  # Iterate over the records
            if record[0] == char:  # We find it!
                current_record = record  # This is the record for current char
                break  # Stop the search
        if current_record is None:  # This means the list does not contain the record for this char yet
            current_record = [char, 0, []]  # Create the record
            records.append(current_record)  # Put the record into the list of records
        current_record[1] += 1  # Increase the count by one
        current_record[2].append(idx)  # Append the position of the character into the list

    for value in records:  # Iterate over the Char_Record
        print value # Print the Char_Record
```

Or, if you need to sort it, you can do what @Dannnno said, or as an example, it can be sorted in this way (although you might have not learned about lambda):

```
records.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Just put that before printing the records.

Or, you can do it using `dict` and `list`:

```
def build_char_records(s):
    record = {}  # Create an empty dictionary
    for idx, char in enumerate(s):  # Iterate over the characters of string with the position specified
        char = char.lower()  # Convert the character into lowercase
        if char not in record:  # If we have not seen the character before, create the Char_Record
            record[char] = [char,0,[]]  # Create a Char_Record and put it in the dictionary
        record[char][1] += 1  # Increase the count by one
        record[char][2].append(idx)  # Append the position of the character into the list
    for value in record.values():  # Iterate over the Char_Record
        print value  # Print the Char_Record
```

Comment: Ok, we can change the dictionary to list, changing the simple reference to `record[char]` with a loop to search. But to sort it, you need the approach by @Dannnno